# detect white text after preprocessing image to extract it with OCR + tesseract 4 (python)

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract

I'am trying to extract text from images (such as online beauty products images) with tesseract OCR and it fails most of the times to detect white text. The chalenge is that the text is mixed (**some text is in black on white and other is white on black**) Is there a way to overcome this and improve the ability of OCR to be able to detect white text?

Please find attached the image after preprocessing (the one that OCR has as an input)

[OCR input image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a8iZx.jpg)

The results of text extraction is this :

a : if 3
é ue
a. . ' sat a
i f |
aa a i

eczema yt
HAND REPAIR CREAM.
BRe ie ccm Sec mea se gern

pe COR EgencuC es
De Uae ene ai Ml.

TS Qiocoar 4 "
: 3 alas, : e

Risted-& recowiniendeda | a
PEC Ry j .

**Also is there a way to extract the text in the circle (curved text) ??**

Answer (score 1):

For the white text, you would need to pre-process the image. Doing this in a robust way is just plain hard, as humans are good at detecting text. Your white-on-black is probably still easy - just estimate the local background and XOR that. Things get harder when you have a hollow font, or letters where the local background is a gradient. No easy answer; it might be necessary to try a few transforms and see which transforms give reasonable outputs.

The garbage input before "eczema" is likely not caused by the white text, but by the fact that it's a logo with highly curved text. Most normal text is written in straight lines, from left to right. So an OCR engine reasonable expects the next character to be immediately to the right, and at the same orientation. For an 'o' this of course doesn't matter, but a 'p' and a 'd' only differ in orientation. So it will be necessary to tell Tesseract about it. Luckily circles are a common-enough case. Tesseract has a Page Segmentation Mode 9, exactly for words in a circle.

Comment: Can you provide an image processing example that is working with dark background and light letters? As you said, it is not easy, however there are already many applications that is working with that kinds of images.